# Undelete a post

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095812/interconnection-between-user-controls). I reviewed it and made some changes in it. Could you please undelete this post?

Comment: It doesn't look considerably better than before.

Comment: It is completely changed. at the beginning it was too broad.

Comment: It still looks too broad.

Comment: screenshot for the <10K http://i.stack.imgur.com/MqVst.png

Comment: why did you send a screenshot @rene?

Comment: So everyone can judge your SO question, not only you and users with more then 10,000 reputation

Comment: It's not really a good idea to ask for undeletion in Meta. When you edit a deleted post to fit [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help), you should flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @dorukayhan, I'm Sorry, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 16):

What is missing from your question is your attempt or a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can judge where you're actually stuck.

Your question is exactly this:

> Consider we have more than one user controls in a form. each one of them have some controls like TextBox, Button inside it. Suppose changing a controls in User Control A change a control in User Control B. How can I make that possible with delegates and events?

What if you create the code for that User Control A and User Control B with a TextBox and a Button and show how you try to wire those controls on the form they are one?

Searching on Stack Overflow should reveal some hits on the same topic as well. Include what you have found and how they help or not help in answering your question.

Because that shows us if we need to explain what a delegate is, or an event, or how state is managed, or how binding works, or a [CurrencyManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager(v=vs.110).aspx) or even a Model-View-Controller, or Model-View-ViewModel or other possible  patterns.

Your question is still too broad.

Comment: Thanks, I consider that and review it again.